# Netlogo - ifelse statement

Tags: if-statement, patch, netlogo

I have a problem in Netlogo, where i should check if a neighbor patch of a specific patch is already colored black.

This is how i thought it could work:

```
ifelse [ask patch xcoord-temp ycoord-temp [ask patches in-radius rnd_radius [pcolor = black]]]?
  [print "true"]
  [print "false"]

Error Message is: Expected a TRUE/FALSE here, rather than a list or block.
```

`xcoord-temp` and `ycoord-temp` are calculated coordinates.

`rnd_radius` is a random radius between 1 and 15.

So does someone has an idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Regards,
John

Answer (score 0):

Okay first, the reporter `patch` receives an identificator that's linked to a patch. If you want to `ask` something to a patch at a certain position you want to use `[patch-at]`[1](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-at).

Second, I don't understand the use of question mark in your code `?`.

Third, by using `[pcolor = black]` the compiler understands you want to `set` rather than get.

Lastly, you can use the word `of` to access values of an agent.

So I would put it out like this:

```
to myprocedure
  ask patch-at xcoord-temp ycoord-temp 
      [
        check-color
      ]
end
to check-color
      ifelse [pcolor] of (patches in-radius rnd_radius) = black
      [print "true"]
      [print "false"]
end
```

Note than I'm using an extra procedure that may not be complete, perhaps it would have to receive the temporal coordinates you use; unless these coordinates are global variables that change overtime, then you can use the procedures like that.

Please tell us if this helps you, I don't have NetLogo installed right now, I did that based on the dictionary.

Edit:
As stated in the comments

`[pcolor] of (patches in-radius rnd_radius)` will return a list, thus it can never equal `black`.

You'll have to ask for an specific neighbor of the patch or perhaps use `one-of` in the list resulting from the previous statement..

Comment: `[pcolor] of patches in-radius ...` will return a list of colors, and a list can never equal `black`, so this will always print `false`.

Comment: You're right, I was only translating his code into mine.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer!
The problem is, that your solution makes another error:
`You can't use XXX in an observer context, because XXX is turtle/patch-only.`
I think it's because of the patch-at?

Comment: Your original code had `patch`, not `patch-at`. If you want absolute coordinates (not relative offsets), then `patch` is correct; perhaps David's substitution of `patch-at` was inadvertent.

Comment: @John of course, to use my code you'd have to fix yours so that only patches call `myprocedure`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and least verbose way would be to write a reporter procedure like this

```
to-report any-black-neighbors-in-radius? [r]
  report any? patches in-radius r with [pcolor = black]
end
```

You can then ask a patch to run this procedure using `r` as a parameter, and either `print` the value, or use it for something else. Like this:

`ask one-of patches [print any-black-neighbors-in-radius 5]`

If you want to ask a particular patch to run it, just ask that patch using `patch`, like so:

`ask patch 5 -5 [print any-black-neighbors-in-radius 3]`

Comment: And if you want to test whether they are all black (rather than at least one), replace `any?` with `all?`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! Yes, this works, it's not exactly doing what i thought, but I think it's another problem i have to look about.
So thanks very much!